# RxJava : insert divider object

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to insert divider object into collection.

```
Observable<String> observable = Observable.from(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" });

Iterable<String> dividedList = observable.flatMapIterable(new Func1<String, Iterable<String>>() {
  @Override public Iterable<String> call(String s) {
    return Lists.newArrayList(s, "divider");
  }
}).toBlocking().toIterable();
```

I wanted `["a", "divider", "b", "divider", "c"]`,
but actually, of course is `["a", "divider", "b", "divider", "c", "divider"]`

How can I do this by using RxJava ?

Answer (score 4):

Just drop the last element using `skipLast` operator !

```
Observable.just("a", "b", "c")
          .flatMap((l) -> Observable.just(l, "divider"))
          .skipLast(1)
          .toBlocking().toIterable();
```

Comment: I just know the pragmatic  use of `skip(1)` or `skipLast(1)`, thanks!

Comment: you may want to use `concatMap` here instead of `flatMap` to guarantee the ordering is preserved.

Answer (score 3):

You can reverse the pairs in order to have [sep, element] and drop the first item emited.

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> interpose(T sep, T[] seq) {
    return Observable.from(seq)
            .flatMap(s -> Observable.just(sep, s))
            .skip(1).toBlocking().toIterable();     
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Iterable<String> dividedList = interpose("|", new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" });
    dividedList.forEach(s -> System.out.print(s.toString()+" "));
    System.out.println();
}
```

> a | b | c | d